# Mix/version images in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I want to use mix on a set of images. First I copy them:

```
mix.copy('resources/images', 'public/images');
```

Then version:

```
mix.version();
```

The above does nothing to the images.

I've also tried specifying the path:

```
mix.version('public/images/*');
```

But I get a no such file or directory error.

How can I version the images?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to solve this?

Comment: @BitByBit See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old question, but for 2019 - laravel mix 4 you can use:

```
mix.copy('resources/images/*', 'public/images');
mix.version();
```

This will version all your copied files. **DON'T** use one of these:

```
mix.copy('resources/images/*', 'public/images/*'); 
mix.copy('resources/images/', 'public/images/*'); 
mix.copyDirectory('resources/images/*', 'public/images');
```

-> it will not version the files then.

The see the result, take a look in the public/mix-manifest.json:

```
"/favicon.ico": "/favicon.ico?id=ecb5fdce0172885513c8",
```

To use it in code, use the laravel mix helper method: mix();

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ mix('favicon.ico') }}" />
```

which will generate something like this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico?id=ecb5fdce0172885513c8" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`version()` (without arguments) is not applied to files passed to `copy()` and `copyDirectory()`.

If you'll look at the source of `mix.version` you'll see that it expands glob synchronously. But all `laravel-mix` operations such as `copy` and `version` are executed asynchronously. This means that `public/images/*` is empty because there are no files yet in `public` directory.

As a workaround you can list files in source directory (from which you copy files, for example `resources`), replace `resources` path segment with `public` and pass this list to `version()`.

In my case I have various assets in `resources` directory so directory tree looks like:

```
- resources
  | - css
  | - fonts
  | - images
  | - js
  | - less
```

I need to copy to `public` and version all these directories except `less` which I need to preprocess and also version.

This is like my `webpack.mix.js` looks like:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix'),
    glob = require('glob');

mix.disableNotifications();

const
    directoriesToCopy = ['css', 'fonts', 'images', 'js'],
    publicDir = 'public/',
    publicCssDir = publicDir + 'css/',
    resourcesDir = 'resources/',
    resourcesLessDir = resourcesDir + 'less/',
    lessFiles = glob.sync('**/*.less', {cwd: resourcesLessDir});

directoriesToCopy.forEach(d => mix.copyDirectory(resourcesDir + d, publicDir + d));

lessFiles.forEach(f => mix.less(resourcesLessDir + f, publicCssDir + f.slice(0, -'less'.length) + 'css'));

mix.version([].concat(...directoriesToCopy.map(d => glob.sync('**/*', {cwd: resourcesDir + d}).map(f => d + '/' + f))).map(f => publicDir + f));
```

Basically I use `glob` to recursively get a list of all files in each copied directory, replace `resources` with `public` in their paths and then pass list of all such files to `mix.version`.