# Webpack mix verion files that use Copy or CopyDirectry

Tags: laravel-5, webpack

- Laravel Mix Version: 1.4.5
- Node Version: v6.10.2
- NPM Version: 3.10.10
- OS:  windows 10 xampp

#### Description:

Undefined index when using copy/copyDirectory and {{ mix() }}

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Create 2 folders in resources

> /css/afolder/afile.css
>
> /css/another/anotherfile.css

Copy the folders with the following:

```
`mix.copy('resources/assets/css/', 'public/css', false);`
```

**or**

```
`mix.copyDirectory('resources/assets/css/', 'public/css');`
```

The files are copied fine, but when using

```
`{{ mix('css/afolder/afile.css') }}`
```

**or**

```
`{{ mix('css/anotherfolder/anotherfile.css') }}`
```

**It returns back**

> Undefined index: css/afolder/afile.css
>
> Undefined index: css/anotherfolder/anotherfile.css

The folders exists:

```
public/css/afolder/afile.css
public/css/anotherfolder/anotherfile.css
```

Mix manifest just shows the following

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=0eaf1649511b8f1c3fd9",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=a86d86d0b7edd1152cc6"
}
```

Full webpackmix file

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');

mix.copy('resources/assets/js/', 'public/js', false);

mix.copy('resources/assets/css/', 'public/css', false);

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.version();
```

Comment: This looks like a bug report template. Are you sure you've posted in the correct place?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375271/746347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack does not apply version on files under `copy()` or `copyDirectory()` methods. Because they runs standalone, outside of webpack build.

If you just copy them, you should use this files like as simple file, that are not under version.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/afolder/afile.css') }}">
```

> The `mix.version()` will automatically version any compiled JavaScript, Sass/Less, or combined files. However, if you'd also like to version extra files as part of your build, simply pass a path, or array of paths, to the method, like so: `mix.version(['public/js/random.js']);`

Answer (score 0):

Webpack mix doesn't work with `copyDirectory()`.

Below is a solution that adds all files from the copied directory to the manifest:

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.copyDirectory('resources/sourceDir/', 'public/destinationDir');

mix.version([
  'destinationDir/**'
])
```

Comment: have you tried running this? because it does not work on me.